# What is the Fourier Transform of $ rect(2Bt)cos[{\omega}_Ct + k_fm(t_k)t] $?

Tags: fourier-transform

> What is the Fourier Transform of $ \text{rect}(2Bt)\text{cos}\left[{\omega}_Ct + k_fm(t_k)t\right] $?

I got the following as the solution:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2B} \text{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega+{\omega}_C+k_fm(t_k) +}{4B}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2B} \text{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega-{\omega}_C-k_fm(t_k) +}{4B}\right)$$

However, in the book it is given as:

$$ \frac{1}{2}  \text{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega+{\omega}_C+k_fm(t_k) +}{4B}\right) + \frac{1}{2}  \text{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega-{\omega}_C-k_fm(t_k) +}{4B}\right)$$

Wolfram alpha shows this:[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier%20transform%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%20rect%282Bt%29cos%28pt%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22w%22)

Comment: Make sure you are all using the same definition.  Factors of 2 and $\pi$ show up in different places with different definitions.

Comment: Surely  this is a maths question and more suitable for Math Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

As garyp said, there is not a single definition of the Fourier transform. People use different definitions, e.g. I use 
$$
{\mathscr{F}}\{f\}(\omega) 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt
$$
Using your function 
$ f(t) = rect(2 B t) \cos(p t)$
yields 
$$
{\mathscr{F}}\{f\}(\omega)
= \frac{sinc(\frac{p - \omega}{4 B}) + sinc(\frac{p + \omega}{4 B})}{4 |B|}
$$
In order to obtain this result, we use:

- the convolution theorem, 
  $
  {\mathscr{F}}\{f \cdot g\}(\omega) 
  = {\mathscr{F}}\{f \}(\omega) *
  {\mathscr{F}}\{g\}(\omega)
  $,
- the "scaling" theorem, 
  $
  {\mathscr{F}}\{f(at)\}(\omega) 
  = \frac{1}{|a|}{\mathscr{F}}\{f\}(\omega/a)
  $,
- the fact that $cos$ transforms to two $\delta$-distributions,
- and the fact that the convolution of a function with $\delta$-distribution is the function evaluated at the point of the  $\delta$-distribution.

Finally, supposing that $t$ has the unit $s$ than $B$ and $p$ have the unit $1/s=Hz$. So, the relation from your book has the wrong unit.